# mysql replication lag huge

Tags: mysql

We have a huge data warehouse (almost 4 terabyte) database that we are replicating to slave and it's lagging 45 hrs behind our master/primary. At this point what is the best method to make replication faster.

Comment: First thing I would do is to stop all reads, and see if replication starts to catch up. You should probably add your qpm stats as well so we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Could you give us more information about your setup (memory, hard drives, etc)? Everything plays a role.  Also, how many read/writes come in, etc etc...

Comment: Lol how did this question get an upvote as written?

Answer (score 0):

mysql replication is single-threaded - that's usually cause of the lag.
you have few options:

- mysql 5.6 introduces parallel replication - if you have many databases that are independent - that should speed things up
- alternatively check out [Tungsten Replicator](http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/) - it's 3rd party implementation of much more flexible replication for mysql [including multithreading]. [this](http://www.slideshare.net/datacharmer/advanced-mysql-replication-techniques) might be also interesting for you.